# How to get camera roll file location in iphone using phonegap?(For creating a custom camera roll from which multiple files can be chosen)

Tags: iphone, file, cordova, camera

I am working on iPhone app using PhoneGap.

In this app I need to show a screen with camera roll pictures and the user should be able to select multiple photos from it.

Using `navigator.camera.getPicture` I can show all images, but user can select only one image from it.

The imageURI returned is 
`file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/946FDEC2-E166-4209-94F8-5E2C70EEDA71/tmp/cdv_photo_010.jpg`

And tried with file api as below.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){ 
    // success get file system
    var sdcard = fileSystem.root;
    sdcard.getDirectory("../../../Media/DCIM/100APPLE",
             {create:false, exclusive: false}, 
             function(dcim){
                 var directoryReader = dcim.createReader();
                 directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries){ 
                 // success get files and folders
                 for(var i=0; i<entries.length; ++i){
                     alert(entries[i].name);
                 }
       });
     }, function(error){
       switch(error.code){
          case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR : alert('NOT_FOUND_ERR');break;
          case FileError.SECURITY_ERR: alert('SECURITY_ERR');break;
          case FileError.ABORT_ERR: alert('ABORT_ERR');break;
          case FileError.NOT_READABLE_ERR: alert('NOT_READABLE_ERR');break;
          case FileError.ENCODING_ERR: alert('ENCODING_ERR');break;
          case FileError.NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: alert('NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR');break;
          case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR: alert('INVALID_STATE_ERR');break;
          case FileError.SYNTAX_ERR: alert('SYNTAX_ERR');break;
          case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: alert('INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR');break;
          case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: alert('QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR');break;
          case FileError.TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: alert('TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR');break;
          case FileError.PATH_EXISTS_ERR: alert('NOT_FOUND_ERR');break;
      }

});
```

This works in simulator.

But when tried in iPhone it shows error and there is no `DCIM` folder inside `../../../Media` in the iPhone.

My iPhone model is `iPhone 4S 16Gb with iOS 6.0`

I would like to know

1. Is there anything wrong with this approach?
2. What is the correct path instead of `../../../Media/DCIM/100APPLE` in which the camera roll pictures are saved?
3. Is there any meta files in which the above mentioned path is stored?
4. Is there any other method to achieve this (option to select multiple files from camera roll) ?

Comment: Hi! Were you be able to get this code to run? I am trying to make an image gallery on IOS, but I have the same issues as you.

Answer (score 0):

For this there are some custom libraries ELCImagePickerController and AGImagePickerController.

https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController

https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController

You can use one of these. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Is there any PhoneGap plugin available?